# What is the best command line tool to concatenate and minify javascript files?

Tags: windows, javascript, minimization

I have a bunch of JavaScript files (.js) that needs minification. I need to concatenate them and minify them during my build process, using a command line tool on **Windows**.

- Concatenation prior to minification
- It should support ECMAScript 2017.
- Obfuscation would be an added bonus

What is currently the best command line tool on Windows for this?